# I am using JBoss 4,2 GA version for one of my projects. "Does the version support RESTful Service"?"

Tags: rest, service, jboss

I am using JBoss 4,2 GA version for one of my projects. My question here is "Does the version support RESTful Service"?. I don't find many helpful tutorials. Can anyone suggest me one?

Comment: JBoss 4.2 precedes JAX-RS. It was released 10 years ago. If you are looking for JAX-RS implementation, you should look at [JBoss WildFly](http://wildfly.org/downloads/) 9 or 10

Answer (score 1):

As @CoolBeans stated, JBoss 4.2 doesn't have a JAX-RS (java api for restful web service) implementation.

Newer versions of JBoss (6 or higher) already have support for this. So you can use a newer version, or just provide a JAX-RS implementation to your jboss 4.2

Here you can find a tutorial for adding resteasy (jboss JAX-RS implementation) to your jboss

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/resteasy-tutorial